# cascades - random button on a listview

Tags: listview, button, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm making an app and I have a listview, and I want there is a button that when pressed, make a triggered a random item listview, to the second page
I have this button, but it does not work

```
Button{
                                                 text:qsTr("Random")

                                                 onClicked: {
                                                     size = groupDataModel.size();
                                                     rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*size); //can also use randInt(0, size);
                                                     listview.triggered(rand);
                                                }

                                             }//Boton Random
```

Here's the full code
http://paste2.org/eea0IkjC

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it please?

Answer (score 0):

`triggered` is the name of the C++ signal. You should call `listview.onTriggered(rand);` if you want your `onTriggered` slot called. However, I'm not sure it's expecting an integer.